# Pass values through url but page could not redirect

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, url, sms

I am using  sms gateway. I want sent the data like the following format through url

```
http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=uname&password=password&to=+911111111111&text=Hello
```

i want to call this url but the present page could not be change, because that page working another function at the same time. Am using header function, it sent sms but the current page function can't work. So any one suggest me a solution

Comment: you can use AJAX call

Comment: Ajax will wildly solve your problem!!!

Comment: You can also use cURL if the page is a PHP page.

Comment: can you show more codes?

Comment: Use curl from PHP . Do not use ajax because you are passing sensitive information like the users password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the jQuery `post`:

```
$.post( "http://127.0.0.1:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms", { username: "uname", password: "password", password: "+911111111111", text: "Hello"  } );
```

it is a shorthand `Ajax` function and will not change your current page.
you can use the callback function to check the request status as well.

See : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to change your method to post instead of get that you have it now.
That way you can post the same string without loading a new page.

Comment: what you mean can you explain?

Comment: post method, sends query string via http message body, and you are posting this data to the page you have set in your form.
<form action="action.php" method="post">

The good thing is that you can post this way the data you want without having to reload/refresh the page. In this example, action.php will execute, get the posted data and do whatever you want it to do.